# Why does comma9.2 not work?

Tags: sas

Can anyone tell me why `comma9.2` is not working in my sas codes?

```
data have;
input x $16.;
y = input(x, comma9.2);
z = input(x, comma9.);
put x= y= z= ;
cards;
1,740.32
5200
520
52
7,425
9,000.00
36,000.00
;
run;
```

Comment: To make this a good question, you should give an explanation of what is not correct.  While it's obvious to me, it may not be obvious to others what the mistake is - and is clearly not obvious to you - and providing the explanation of what is wrong will help others with the same problem (and will help get better answers).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Reeza's answer:

Informat decimal places do not quite work the way Format decimal places do.  In almost all cases, you will not want to or need to specify the `d` in the informat.  `Comma9.` is almost always correct, no matter how many decimal places you expect - even if you expect always two.

The only use informat decimal places serve is when you have a number like `12345600`, which has no decimal in it, but it ought to (the last two zeros are after the decimal).

```
data _null_;
  input numval 8.2;
  put numval=;
  datalines;
12345600
12345605
99999989
1857.145
;;;;
run;
```

This was something that was common once upon a time in the age of punch cards, particularly for accounting; since everything was in dollars and cents, you could save a column by leaving out the decimal, and just read everything in with two decimals.  It is no longer common in most fields (at least in my experience), but SAS is always backwards compatible.

SAS will ignore the `.d` specification if it encounters a decimal point in the data (and will then use the location of that decimal to read in the value correctly), but if there are no decimal points in the data it may read it in incorrectly if you specify the `.d`.  Notice in my example the final row has a decimal point followed by three decimal places, and is read in correctly.

You can read [SAS Documentation](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59498.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Comma9.2 assumes that values will always have 2 decimal places.

Comment: Thank you very much, Reeza. So, if there are mixed cases, I should use comma9., right?